# Which namespace is python global functions in

Tags: python

I use globals() to get the all the variable and functions, but could not find function abs. So wondering which namespace is in for this kind of global python functions ?

Comment: The Python interpreter has a number of functions built into it that are always available but I'm not sure where you could get and from which namespace.

Comment: `__builtins__`.